# New portable hand held recorders

Tags: handheld, portable-recorder

Hi everybody,
I was wondering if any of you had any chance to test the Korg MR-2 or the new Roland R-26 hand held recorders. If so, what's your opinion on both?
I tried searching for reviews but they're too new in the market, so there's nothing to read about the performance on both except for the technical aspects.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this thread: http://socialsounddesign.com/questions/10584/lets-have-an-updated-chat-about-portable-recorders

Whilst there aren't any answers for your questions, it's a suitable place to ask :)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I have the Roland R26

The internal mics are useful in a pinch but does not sound as nice as the Sony m10 or d50 internal mics. I did quite a lot of tests comparing the internal mics to the Sony m10, and the m10 has less noise, better definition/depth.
The R26 directional mics are very directional giving a pretty wide stereo image. They work ok with louder sounds but not that we'll with ambiances.
I decided to keep mine despite this as I like the multichannel recording possibilities, and it was easy to open so I will make a alternative mic front end for my unit.
Either a front rear x/y setup, or I might try it with a tetra style mic.

Mic amps are pretty decent but I have not hade the time to compare them to a sound devices pre yet.

Comment: Erik did you had any experience with h4n? and if yes then how would you compare h4n to r26? as far as i understand external mic preamps are by far better on roland, but what about on board mics?

Comment: No no proper comparisions yet unfortunately. 
I'll try to find the time one day... 
I dont have access to the H4n, but I'll try to make a test between R26/M10/LS10

Comment: ok, that would be nice too ;)

Answer (score 0):

I added this to another thread but i'll add what I wrote here as well.

I had the MR-1 and loved it until the battery died. But with the price of the MR-2 around the $699 mark, I would go with the Sony D50, which is approx the same price. In my opinion the 1Bit audio recording on the MR recorders is pointless and uses way to much space, you have to convert down to use it in any DAW anyway so I never saw the point in recording with the 1bit formats. Perhaps in the future IF DAW's support that format it will be useful, but I don't think they will ever support it. The fact that no other manufacturer is making 1bit recorders should tell you something!!

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of new recorders, the $199 Tascam DR-40 (XLR input, 4 tracks, and all that jazz) seems like a pretty serious contender for amateur sound work.